# Highcharts: Change color of bubbles in one serie

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart

Can I set different colors for a serie in a bubble chart? I try setting the property "color" but not work.

```
        data: [{
            x: 23,
            y: 22,
            z: 200,
            name:"point1",
            color: 'red'
        }, {
            x: 43,
            y: 12,
            z: 100,
            name:"point2",
            color:'yellow'
        }]
```

Maybe I can use a label in the serie but I prefer the change the bubble, it is possible?

```
dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: 'red'
}
```

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVF8/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each point that needs a unique color will need its own series object. It's a little weird, but this works:

```
    series: [{
        data: [{
            x: 23,
            y: 22,
            z: 200,
            name:"point1"
        }, {
            x: 43,
            y: 12,
            z: 100,
            name:"point2",
        }],
        color: "yellow"
    },{
        data: [{
            x: 50,
            y: 22,
            z: 150,
            name:"point3"
        }, {
            x: 43,
            y: -30,
            z: 100,
            name:"point4",
        }],
        color: "blue"
    }]
```

Check out this demo from the site: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble-3d

And here is a js fiddle with your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/tqVF8/7/

Comment: Thanks, but is there another way? And following your example the color can't be set, the color must be outside of data, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVF8/6/

Comment: yeah you're absolutely correct, sorry it was a copy-paste fail. I'll update the code in the answer but I'm afraid I don't know another way of doing it. good luck :)

Comment: I use your example any way :P thank you. I just add a disabled legend: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVF8/8/

Answer (score 9):

In your case, you can add the property "fillColor"

```
 data: [{
            x: 23,
            y: 22,
            z: 200,
            name:"point1",
            color: 'red',
            fillColor : 'red'
        }, {
            x: 43,
            y: 12,
            z: 100,
            name:"point2",
            color:'yellow',
            fillColor : 'yellow'
        }]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/tqVF8/17/